# How to start Django from code in background?

Tags: python, django

One can easily start Django using management command like this:

```
management.call_command('runserver', interactive=False)
```

But it actually blocks execution.
Any workaround apart from subprocess/threading/multiprocessing.

I mean how to do it in more native fashion?

Comment: What do you mean by management.py?

Comment: Oh, Sorry, I'm not absolutely read that. :)

Answer (score 0):

A management command is *not* "starting django".

You "start django" by deploying on any number of web servers, each of which has methods to run in the background.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/

Dynamically deploying django isn't something I've seen, but I suppose you could write some scripts that generate webserver configuration files.

`manage.py runserver` should never be used for production environments / uses.

If that was just an example, and you actually want to run other asynchronous management commands, the accepted community answer to to use a task queue like Celery.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/

You could then fire off 10000 non blocking management commands to be consumed "in the future" at some point by celery workers.

Comment: It's not really for production usage but mostly for Django consumer testing. Anyway I like your idea about Celery.